# Action of infinite symmetric groups on iterated power sets

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, lo.logic

Let $X$ be an infinite set, and $k \ge 1$ be a natural number.  We work without the axiom of choice.

Let $G_0$ be the full symmetric group on $X$, and let $G_1$ be the
full symmetric group on ${\cal P}(X)$, the power set of $X$. Both
these groups act on ${\cal P}^k(X)$ (the $k$-fold power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\cdots(X)\cdots)$ of $X$)
in a natural way, with $G_0$ a subgroup of $G_1$. So in ${\cal P}^k(X)$ the orbits of $G_1$ split into orbits of $G_0$.

> Is the following true in ZF: for all $k\ge 1$, for all distinct elements $a\neq b$ of ${\cal P}^k(X)$
>   that belong to the same $G_1$-orbit, there exists $\sigma \in G_1$ such that
>   $\sigma(a)$ and $\sigma(b)$ belong to distinct $G_0$-orbits?

A positive result would have nice consequences for the model theory of Russell-Ramsey typed set theory, but I'll say nothing about that for the moment!

Comment: What does $k >> 1$ stand for?

Comment: Also, if you could make the part about "fissioning" a bit more explicit, that would be quite helpful.

Comment: Means $k$ much bigger than 1.  I actually want it to hold for arbitrarily large $k$.  `fissioning' is a synonym of `splits'.  Sorry.   Thank you for your attention to this question!  tf

Comment: It better be the case here that $G_0$ is *not* a normal subgroup of $G_1$.

Comment: I think it's straightforward to show that it isn't.

Comment: We m-a-y be at cross purposes.. I am interested in the action of these two groups on ${\cal P}^k(X)$, the $k$-times power set of $X$, not in their action on the cartesian product of $k$ copies of ${\cal P}(X)$.   I am confident that the conjecture is true for small $k$. Or am i misreading you..? - tf

Comment: You're right, I understood $P(X)^k$, so my comment does not apply. (Had you called it $k$-times iterated power set, I wouldn't have made the confusion.) Btw my argument for the cartesian power is completely flawed...

Comment: By the way, your post would benefit of some streamline: remove the 1st paragraph, remove the confusing sentence "Clearly, we cannot expect them to...". Ask more concisely and then add comments if they can help understanding the question, put some context, or point out some difficulty/trap, etc.

Comment: Do you have *any* mitigating assumptions on $X$? For example, if $|X^2|=|X|$ then this is inherited by taking power sets and finite products. The same goes for $|X|+|X|=|X|$ (which actually gives you $2^X\cdot 2^X=2^{X+X}=2^X$, which is stronger).

Comment: One more thing which made me confused (and probably not only me) is asking "for all large enough $k$" which suggests that it might be false for small $k$. While it seems that $k$ small is easier and you want the result for all $k$.

Comment: One more instance of missing context is "put all thought of axiom of choice out of your mind". In standard language this translates as "We work without the axiom of choice." And this raises the question what occurs assuming AC. If it's obviously yes, you should have written it. Otherwise, the question should certainly first be solved assuming AC, to set up ideas.

Comment: In answer to Asaf's question, yes in the realistic cases of interest $X$ will be an iterated power set of an infinite set.  So $X$ will indeed be idemmultiple.  I'm not sure how much that would help, but it's an assumption i'd be willing to make. But not AC!  Thanks!

Comment: Thomas, do you know that sufficiently iterated power sets are idemmultiple? I only know that assuming the "base set" was idempotent (additively).

Comment: Yes, i think so. If $X$ is not dedekind finite then its power set has a countable partition, the double power set has a countable subset, the triple power set is the same size as the union of two disjoinrt copies of itself and the quadruple power set is idemmultiple.

Comment: Why is the power set of a Dedekind-infinite set can be split into two parts? Take a $\omega_1$-amorphous set $X$, then $\mathcal P(X)$ is the sum of countable and co-countable subsets. How is it the sum of two copies of itself?

Comment: If $x = x+1$ then $2^x =2^x \cdot 2$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comment (no longer an answer) about the case $k=2$, assuming the axiom of choice, and in particular assuming that $X$ is presented in one-on-one correspondence with some cardinal.  Perhaps this can be generalized substantially.

Now $a,b\in{\cal P}^2(X)$ are in the same $G_1$ orbit iff they have the same cardinality.  [Update: their complements should also have the same cardinality, and the construction below assumes infinite complements.]  So for this case, we want to know:  Given $a,b\subset {\cal P}(X)$ of the same infinite cardinality, are there sets $c,d\subset {\cal P}(X)$ of that same cardinality but in different $G_0$ orbits?

The answer to that question is yes. For $S\in{\cal P}(X)$, let
\begin{align}
f(S)&=\{s+4:s\in S\}\cup\{1,2,3\}\\
c&=\{f(S):S\in a\}\cup \{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,1\}\}\\
d&=\{f(S):S\in b\}\cup \{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}
\end{align}
Clearly $a,b,c,d$ are all of the same cardinality, and:

- i) $\exists x\in X$ which appears in all but one element of $c$.
- ii) $\nexists x\in X$ which appears in all but one element of $d$.

These properties are invariant under $G_0$ actions, so $c$ and $d$ are in different $G_0$ orbits.

Comment: The same should work for all $k$ too, no? I mean, take two copies of the same leveled forest of height $k-1$ and let them grow differently to the $k$th level (differently means having, say, all cardinalities of all new branches just pairwise different)

Comment: I assume so, but I don't trust my ability to visualize or reason informally about $\cal{P(P(P(X)))}$.

Comment: Mmm actually I oversimplified - in general one has leveled graphs that are not necessarily forests. But still I believe such a graph faithfully represents an element of $\mathcal P^k(X)$. Given one such, say $\mathfrak S$, place its elements on the bottom level, elements of $\bigcup\mathfrak S$ above them, elements of $\bigcup\bigcup\mathfrak S$ above those, etc. The relation is just $\ni$. Any embedding of the top level of every such height $k$ leveled graph into $X$ then determines an element of $\mathcal P^k(X)$ provided any two nodes at any level have distinct successor sets above them.

Comment: Yes, k=2 is easy because, as you say, two things belong to the same $G_1$-orbit iff they [and their *complements*, actually] are equinumerous. However, for the purposes for which i need this result, it is quite important to have a proof that doesn't use AC.  And i need it for arbitrarily large $k$. Thank you all for your interest!

Comment: @ThomasForster, the phrase "put all thought of the axiom of choice out of your mind" was not helpful -- it was ambiguous between "avoid" and "don't worry about".  I will edit the question.